# Transcoding with UVD?

Tags: video, transcode, hardware-acceleration

Is there a way to use [UVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Video_Decoder) for transcoding? E.g. for decoding video for recompression. I'm not looking for accelerating the actual encoding process, just the decoding.

If it's not possible, than is it a hardware limitation?

Comment: Wow, this is the oldest available 'Tumbleweed' awarded question...